# how Splitting Dataset by class?

Tags: python

I want to separate my data set by class. Get a dataset that has 1000 examples of each .
My classes are: 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9;

```
import tensorflow 

import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier 

import pandas as pd


(x_train, y_train) , (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

And i try this code :

```
#retoure une matrice au format (10000 , 784)
def dataParClasse(x , y):
liste = []

for j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(y)):    
        if y[i]==j:
            liste.append(x[i]) 
            total = total + 1
            if total==1000:
                break
            
liste = np.array(liste)
liste = liste.reshape(len(liste), -1)
return liste
```

But it's don't work so i need our help please; thanks in advance

Comment: why dont you use train_test-spit ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. !

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train) , (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

def dataParClasse(x, y):
    liste = []

    for j in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]:
        total = 0
        for i in range(len(y)):
            if y[i] == j:
                liste.append(x[i])
        total = total + 1
        if total == 1000:
            break

    liste = np.array(liste)
    liste = liste.reshape(len(liste), -1)

    return liste

liste_split = dataParClasse(x_train,y_train)
liste_split = liste_split.reshape(x_train.shape)
```